# Best Practices: Database app programming patterns

Tags: database

I have written many database (MySQL) web apps so far but I always think my structure is kinda clumsy. I want to improve the programming/design pattern I use, hoping for some advice here. Particularly, I cannot find a structure that complements an OOP approach that encapsulates the implementation of the database (schema). I

Think my question can be best explained by example. There are 2 approaches I use now say I have an Invoice object/class:

first is to use static member functions

```
class Invoice
{
   int id;
   string ref;
   int customer_id;
   date created;
   date due;

   static id create();
   static bool update(id, field1, field2, ...);
   static bool delete(id);
   static bool get(id);
};
```

The second approach is to put every thing in a database object:

```
class Database extends ProprietaryDBConnecter, Singleton
{
   id createInvoice();
   bool updateInvoice(id, field1, field2, ...);
   bool deleteInvoice(id);
   bool getInvoice(id);

   id createCustomer();
   bool updateCustomer(id, field1, field2, ...);
   bool deleteCustomer(id);
   bool getCustomer(id);

   // etc...
}
```

I find that both ways the (SQL) member functions are very much unseparable from the "view", in that the "view" determines what the classes needs to have and hence seems to break the document/view architecture.

Also, it seems kind of inefficient for example a SELECT statement should only select what is needed, but the presence of member variables in Invoice seems to imply "guaranteed data".

Don't know if I explained the question clearly, What are some other best approaches to this architecture/design pattern/what-it-is-known-as?

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well I suppose that you could use an ORM.

But really, database design should NOT follow OOP priciples, it should follow database design priciples such as normalization.  And it should be designed at the database not in the application. And the data integrity rules should be enforced at the database level not by the application.

I would suggest you read some database design books and, then, read about performance tuning the database of your choice.

Comment: +1 for not everything must be OOP (even if some ORMs are quite nice!)

Comment: O/RMs are nice, but using them doesn't mean you can't conform to good database design.

Comment: @David, I agree that is true in the hands of someone who knows what he is doing. And I did suggest he look at an ORM, but really if you don't know database design first, an ORM is a dangerous tool.

Comment: That's a good point that data integrity rules can be enforced at the database level.  However, sometimes it makes sense to put some rules (such as 'project must always contain more than 5 team members') in the application if the rules are subject to change, and only the application will be modifying data.

Comment: The application is almost never the only thing that modifies data. Business rules not put into the database tend to very easily get violated when someone needs to make a quick change to a large chunk of data to support some data fix.

Comment: wow... thanks everyone for the inputs (including all answerers and commenters). should've asked this question earlier. I haven't check what is ORM, and i can't understand all your tech-talk right now, so i think i will be learning a lot this weekend.

Comment: Putting data validation rules into the application's code is fine, but they should also always be implemented at the database level regardless of what's going on with the application. As HLGEM says, one day, someone will come along and modify the data without using the application, either directly executing SQL against the db or with another app which uses the same db (which was never expected when the original app was created, but now exists).

Answer (score 10):

> I cannot find a structure that
>   complements an OOP approach that
>   encapsulates the implementation of the
>   database

Seems like you're describing the [Object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_impedance_mismatch).

There are number of things that are supposed to solve this OODBMS, ORM tools, a [host](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/15466/162) of data access tools.

I think the fact that there's so many solutions leads me to believe that One True Solution™ doesn't exist.

So you can pick any direction you like secure in the knowledge that some people will hate it and some will love it.

Comment: Looks like it is, in a more rigourous way.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an ORM wrapper, use a database that supports OOP style storage like [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB).

> **MongoDB** (from "hu​**mongo**​us") is a cross-platform [document-oriented database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) system. Classified as a "[NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)" database, MongoDB eschews the traditional table-based [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) structure in favor of [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)-like documents with dynamic schemas (MongoDB calls the format [BSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON)), making the integration of data in certain types of applications easier and faster...